# Python callable to define args, kwargs as a tuple

Tags: python, arguments

Is there some library or callable that lets you do something like the following?

```
args, kwargs = get_args(True, 'seven', blah=None, x='y')
```

So that

```
args == [True, 'seven']
kwargs == {'blah': None, 'x': 'y'}
```

I guess my google foo is weak. Surely something like this is built into python, but I cannot find such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in, but you could easily just make your own:

```
def get_args(*args, **kwargs):
    return args, kwargs
```

The `*` (splat) operator is for unpacking arguments like this- it's fairly simple to wrap it in a function.

Comment: Wow. Headsmack. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_args(*args, **kwargs):
    return list(args), kwargs
```